# How can I modify the windowSet in XMonad?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I have a function that looks like:

```
sinkFocus :: StackSet i l a s sd -> Maybe (StackSet i l a s sd)
sinkFocus = (fmap . flip sink) <*> peek
```

However I would like an `X ()` so that I can use it.  For example `additionalKeys` uses an `X ()`.

The documentation says that `X` is a `IO` with some state and reader transformers, so I am under the impression that the `StackSet` is contained within the state of `X`.  So in theory it should be possible to modify the relevant part of the state.  However the state accessible is `XState` not the `StackState` I want, so I need to be able to turn my function on `StackState` to one on `XState`.

This would be easy enough if I had a function of the type

```
(StackSet i l a s sd -> StackSet i l a s sd) -> X ()
```

However after digging around in the documentation I haven't been able to piece together a way to do this yet.  Is there a way to take a function on `StackSet` and make an `X ()` that performs that function?

Answer (score 2):

The `X` monad has an instance of `MonadState`

```
instance MonadState XState X
```

So we can use `modify` as

```
modify :: (XState -> XState) -> X ()
```

So we need to turn out function to one on `XState`s.  And if we look at the definition

```
XState
    windowset :: !WindowSet
    mapped :: !(Set Window)
    waitingUnmap :: !(Map Window Int)
    dragging :: !(Maybe (Position -> Position -> X (), X ())) 
    numberlockMask :: !KeyMask
    extensibleState :: !(Map String (Either String StateExtension))
```

we will see `WindowSet` which is a type alias for a particular `StackState`.  So you can turn a function from `StackState`s into one on `XState`s like so:

```
overWindowSet :: (WindowSet -> WindowSet) -> XState -> XState
overWindowSet f xState = xState { windowset = f (windowset xState) }
```

This can be combined with `modify` to make the complete function you would like:

```
modify . overWindowSet
```

Comment: I don't mind downvotes, but if you have an issue with the answer I would be happy to improve it.

Comment: Hi! I think what you should really use is the function [`windows`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Operations.html#v:windows) from `XMonad.Operations`. This function does a [lot of work](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.0/docs/src/XMonad.Operations.html#windows) to take the modification into account.